# Summarizing multiple clustering results

Tags: self-study, clustering, multilevel-analysis

I'm working on a problem where observations are being clustered within groups but I'd also like to compare the groups. However I am not sure of the best way to compare the groups.

In total I have about 1,000 groups each containing 5 clusters created using k-means. The clusters are based on anywhere from 100-10,000 data points.

For a single group, I can examine the clusters and calculate the within- and between-cluster variation, as well as the cluster means, etc.

However since I have 1,000 groups I'm trying to find different ways I can summarize these data. For example perhaps plotting the groups' mean within-cluster variation vs. mean between-cluster variation (so there is a single point per group).

Most of my ideas are simply to take the mean of something. Are there any better/other methods for summarizing group clusters?

Comment: What is the *purpose* of your analysis?  Are you trying to find the group with the greatest inter-group variation?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the purpose is to reduce the information in each "group" by "prototypes" (i.e. clusters) and to then compare the groups in terms of their prototypes.

Comment: After clustering within a group, you could calculate several cluster quality indicators (silhouette index, Dunn's index, Davies-Bouldin index, Hubert's $\Gamma$), and then compare these across groups.

Comment: @LEP I am thinking that the clustering aspect is less important and the comparison of the groups is more so. Can I just do a one-way anova for each group?

Comment: Sure, one-way ANOVA will work, but recall that will only address one feature across all the groups (univariate).  You could test many of the same features across many groups using a Hotelling test (MANOVA).   Also, through chance alone, you could get significantly different means, so you'd need to partition to objects in each group into folds (cross-validation) and then keep an average value of e.g. -log(p-value).

Comment: Regarding CV during ANOVA, if you randomly generated 100 values of a variate in 3 groups, and ran ANOVA to determine if the three averages (based on $n=100$ in each group) are significantly different you can obtain significance by chance alone.   However, if you e.g. sampled 20%,30%,40%, or 50% of the objects from each group and ran ANOVA on the smaller sample sizes, then kept a running average of -log(p-value) for every fold and repeated this, say, 10 times, you could minimize chances of a obtaining significant results by chance alone.

Comment: @LEP I expect that the clusters within each group will differ – so I expect that the ANOVA will nearly always be "significant".

Comment: You could just run ANOVA, and then use a modified Type I error level (Bonferroni or Sidak $\alpha^* = \alpha /\#tests$) as the p-value criterion, or use Benjamini-Hochberg FDR.  From a machine learning perspective, straightforward inferential hypothesis testing won't cut it alone -- you'd have to use CV at every step.